# Retrieve details of a runlist from a node using CHEF

Tags: attributes, chef-infra

How to retrieve the names of all the cookbooks/profiles which are listed on a specific node's runlist using CHEF?

The ohai attribute `node['recipes']` doesn't give me the list of recipes that are in the runlist of a specified node.

Is there any other way of retrieving the runlist of a specific node so that certain checks can be applied on the retrieved information of the runlist of a specific node?

Comment: Do you mean you would like to find node information through Chef recipe or through `knife` when you mention "using CHEF"?

Comment: would be great to know both the ways of doing it; via recipes and/or via knife.

Comment: `knife` is quite easy, `knife node show NODENAME -a 'run_list'`

Comment: You may need to successfully converge the node before the node attributes appear in the node database and in search.  The attributes of concern will be `node['run_list']`, `node['recipes']`, `node['expanded_run_list']`, and `node['roles']` with varying levels of detail.  If you have an old client (e.g. Chef 12) then those node attributes may not appear or may not be fully populated.

Answer (score 0):

Chef [search](https://docs.chef.io/chef_search/) can be done on the data indexed in the Chef Server using:

**`knife` on workstations**

`knife` command can be used on workstations to search node data. If the node name is known and we want to see the run_list *attribute* of the example node `testbox1.home.net`:

```sh
knife node show testbox1.home.net -a 'run_list'
```

If the node name is not known, but we know a cookbook is it's run_list. This will return nodes that match `recipe[my_cookbook]` in their run_list:

```sh
knife search node 'run_list:recipe\[my_cookbook\]'
```

**`search` from clients through Chef recipes**

Similar searches can be performed from within "recipes" using the `search` functionality.

If the node name is known and we want to fetch the run_list for `testbox1.home.net`. In my `recipes/default.rb`:

```rb
search(:node, 'name:testbox1*', 
  :filter_result => {
    'name' => [ 'name' ],
    'runlist' => [ 'run_list' ]
 } ).each do |details|
    puts "#{details['name']}: #{details['runlist']}"
end
```

If node name is not known, but we know that `recipe[my_cookbook]` is in it's run_list. In my `recipes/default.rb`:

```rb
search(:node, 'run_list:recipe\[cookbook1\]',
  :filter_result => {
    'name' => [ 'name' ],
    'runlist' => [ 'expanded_run_list' ]
  } ).each do |details|
    puts "#{details['name']}: #{details['runlist']}"
end
```

*Note*: I have applied filters to extract only the data required for examples above. If `:filter_result` is omitted then complete information will be retrieved into `details`.